# How much does include statements hinder performance?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am currently writing a node server, using express and ejs for the tempting engine. Some of my .ejs files have 7 - 8 include statements for partials nested inside of them. I was wondering if this is resource intensive, or if it will be fine.

Comment: Profile it. Performance is not the absolute property.

Comment: Includes are probably cached (at least by the OS, maybe by ejs) so you may see a hit the first time they are loaded, but probably not much at all after that.

Comment: How can I know if ejs caches the includes?

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question? Even i want to know how much overhead the includes actually adds.

Comment: Nope, had no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EJS maintainer here.

First off, if you're reading the same file many times in a row, the filesystem will cache it on that level.

However, if you want maximum performance, set `cache: true` in the options. ([docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs#options)) You must be using `renderFile()` or passing in the filename to get this to work. If you're using Express, `cache: true` is set automatically when `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`.

Keep in mind that this assumes that your files never change. i.e. if you change a file, EJS will just use the old cached version until you restart the server process.

Comment: Thank you. I feel a lot more comfortable now.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the include load time for 29 partials:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<? console.time('ejsIncludeTime') ?>
<?include ../partials/head ?>

<body>

   <? include ../partials/header ?>

      <? include ../partials/a ?>
      <? include ../partials/b ?>
      <? include ../partials/c ?>
      <? include ../partials/d ?>
      <? include ../partials/e ?>
      <? include ../partials/f ?>
      <? include ../partials/g ?>
      <? include ../partials/h ?>
      <? include ../partials/i ?>
      <? include ../partials/j ?>
      <? include ../partials/k ?>
      <? include ../partials/l ?>
      <? include ../partials/m ?>
      <? include ../partials/n ?>
      <? include ../partials/o ?>
      <? include ../partials/p ?>
      <? include ../partials/q ?>
      <? include ../partials/r ?>
      <? include ../partials/s ?>
      <? include ../partials/t ?>
      <? include ../partials/u ?>
      <? include ../partials/v ?>
      <? include ../partials/w ?>
      <? include ../partials/x ?>
      <? include ../partials/y ?>
      <? include ../partials/z ?>

    <? include ../partials/footer ?>

    <? console.timeEnd('ejsIncludeTime') ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Each partial from a-z contains 120 or more lines of html. Here's how it goes:

- First hit after the server restart `ejsIncludeTime: 0.175ms`
- Consequent hits `ejsIncludeTime`: `0.078ms`,  `0.068ms`, `0.058ms`, `0.067ms`, `0.077ms`
- Restart the server again and hit `ejsIncludeTime: 0.157ms`
- Consequent hits `0.168ms`(hit after a few minutes gap), `0.044ms`, `0.052ms`

It therefore appears that there's caching involved on some level. The first hit always takes 0.150+ms of include time. Consequent hits are always much less time consuming except for an occasional peak like 0.168ms (can't really explain why. Maybe cache miss).